# Switch statement > possible to include multiple case matches in a single case?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'd like to pass multiple values in a single switch case. I realize its not possible they way I'm trying to do it. Is there another way, short of placing each case on its on line?

```
switch(get_option('my_template'))
{
case 'test1', 'test2':
return 850;
break;

default:
return 950;
}
```

Comment: What? Of course PHP doesn't have features found in such advanced languages such as Bash

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
switch(get_option('my_template')) {
    case 'test1':
    case 'test2':
        return 850;
        break;    
    default:
        return 950;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use `break;` on your case, execution just falls into the next case. You can use this to your advantage by stacking each of your cases together, e.g.:

```
switch(get_option('my_template')) {
  case 'test1':
  case 'test2':
    return 850;
    break; 
  default:
    return 950;
}
```

Because there is no `break;` on the 'test1' case, when execution ends on that case (i.e. immediately, since there is no logic in it), control will then fall to the 'test2' case, which will end at its `break` statement.

In this case, the `break` isn't even needed for these cases, since the `return` statement will take care of breaking out of the `switch` on its own.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion on clearing the break statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Within the switch structure i dont believe there is any way of doing something like an 'or' on one line.  this would be the simplest way:

```
switch(get_option('my_template')) 
{ 
   case 'test1':
   case 'test2': 
     return 850; break;  

   default:
     return 950; 
}
```

But, especially if you are only returning a value and not executing code, i would reccomend doing the following:

```
$switchTable = array('test1' => 850, 'test2' => 850);
$get_opt = get_option('my_template');
if in_array($get_opt, $switchTable)
    return $switchTable[$get_opt];
else return 950;
```

Comment: can also use ternary if you prefer to the if/else `return in_array($get_opt, $switchTable) ? $switchTable[$get_opt] : 950;`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as close as you can get.

```
switch(get_option('my_template'))
{
    case 'test1':
    case 'test2':
    return 850;
    break;

    default:
    return 950;
}
```

Edited with correction.

Comment: Given that each item does a return, there is also no need for the break statements.  I would instead suggest that you set a variable to 850 or 950 here in case you need the value inside of the function after the fact later, and then you will have only one return statement, which is an arguable psuedo-standard.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
switch(get_option('my_template'))
{
    case 'test1':
    case 'test2':
        return 850;
        break;

    default:
        return 950;
}
```